# NServiceBus: need to configure channels for my Gateway with code

Tags: nservicebus

I'm engaged in building NServiceBus Gateway handler, and I need to avoid config files so that all configuration is defined inside c# classes. As a result I have to convert the following section to c# code

```
<GatewayConfig>
    <Channels>
       <Channel Address="http://localhost:25899/SiteB/" ChannelType="Http" Default="true"/>
    </Channels>
 </GatewayConfig>
```

I've found GatewayConfig, ChannelCollection and ChannelConfig in a NServiceBus.Config namespace, but I can not link them together, coz GatewayConfig refers to ChannelCollection, but ChannelCollection has nothing to do with ChannelConfig. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found the way to do it as I installed Reflector and looked into the implementation. There is a ChannelCollection.CreateNewElement() method returning back System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement. NServiceBus overriden the method instantiating ChannelConfig inside it, so all I have to do is to cast ConfigurationElement type to ChannelConfig type which is far from intuitive interface. Looks like this NServiceBus.Config.ChannelCollection is kind of unfinished work, because if you look at other collections like NServiceBus.Config.MessageEndpointMappingCollection you can find there all necessary type-safe methods to work with its child elements NServiceBus.Config.MessageEndpointMapping, so I think NServiceBus team was just lazy to make the same for ChannelCollection.

UPDATE: as CreateNewElement() method is protected, I have to implement my own class inherited from ChannelCollection to make a method adding new ChannelConfig element publicly available

Answer (score 2):

Just create a class implementing IProvideConfiguration of GatewayConfig. That gives you a way to provide your own config. Look at the pubsub sample for the exact details on how to do this.